# How should I call a class to check if it returns null?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, null

I have the following code in a class "Shop":

```
public Item sellItem()
{
    displayItems();
    int indexID = Shop.getInput();
    if (indexID <= -1 && indexID >= wares.length)
    {
        System.out.println("Null"); // For testing purposes
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return wares[indexID];
    }
}
```

And I'd like to know how to write an `if` statement checking if this method is returning `null` for my `while` loop in my main class:

```
int shopInput = scan.nextInt();
if(shopInput >= 1 && shopInput <= allShops.length)
{
   boolean leaveShop = true;
   while(leaveShop)
   {
      allShops[shopInput - 1].sellItem();
      if(???????? == null);
      {
         System.out.println("still null"); // For testing purposes
         leaveShop = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried if (allShops[shopInput - 1].sellItem() == null) {....}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item item = allShops[shopInput - 1].sellItem();
if (item == null) {
    System.out.println("still null"); // For testing purposes
    ...
}
```

(note that I removed the `;` from the end of the `if` line)

Comment: to check for null you have to use != null

Comment: But he's trying to print `"still null"` if it is `null`, so I think `== null` is correct, no?

Comment: look at my response. if( ! item != null)

Comment: Why use a double negative?

Comment: becuase == null is illegal in java. It wont compile

Comment: @ColinGillespie Uhh... what? I use `==null` all the time. Why in the world would that be illegal?

Comment: That solved my compile error, but now I'm stuck in the `while` loop, putting in an entry that's outside the `indexID` array doesn't set `leaveShop` to `false`, in tern, ending my `while` loop.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart omg sorry, thats only for primitives. my bad.

Comment: @ColinGillespie, `!item != null` gives `error: bad operand type Item for unary operator '!'`

Comment: yes my mistake again. surround the "item != null" with parenthesis ()

Comment: @ColinGillespie That doesn't allow me to exit my `while` loops with inputs outside my `indexID` array. It essentially works the same way `item == null` does

Comment: I think the question originally asked has been answered and if you're still having problems with other parts of the code such as the `while` loop it may be best to open a new question and mark this one as answered, since the comments are getting lengthy here

Comment: @ColinGillespie then my `while` loop is sound, because putting `item != null` ends the loop. My problem still lies in setting an object return to `null` and checking IF it was set to `null`...
@StuartM is there anything you can see in my code that would prevent me from setting an object return to `null` and then calling the object to check to see if it's `null`? I can provide more code if you need it.

Comment: Well if you're talking about calling a method on a `null` reference, that's not going to work and will throw an exception. I'm not clear on the remaining issue, some more code examples or a fresh question would help

Comment: @StuartM I'll try to rephrase or provide more information, I'm sorry if this is all incoherent blither to you guys. I'm frustrated, the project is due soon, and I'm a few drinks in... Basically, I have the method inside the `Shop` class which is supposed to check if the user inputs an index ID number which is between 1 and `wares.length` (the maximum number of items in my `wares[]` array). If it's NOT, I want the method to return `null` instead of the `wares[indexID]`. I then need to call the return of the method and see if it is equal to `null` or not. I don't know if that's any clearer :c

Comment: It seems like the code you have so far would do what you're describing, unless you still have the `;` character on the end of the `if (...)` line, which would mean the `if` body is a no-op and it would always be setting `leaveShop = false`

Comment: @StuartM I removed the `;`, I'm not sure where that came from, probably just habit and I didn't notice I put it there. No matter what I do with the current code, no matter my input, I can never get it to print "still null" and exit the `while` loop. One thing I haven't mentioned before is that it's inside ANOTHER `while` loop, that one designed to offer a list of shops with an exit option, but it doesn't seem to interfere with the nested `while` loop. When I set `if(item != null)` it exits the shop and offers the list of other shops as per intended.. If you think that's important, I'll post it

Comment: Does `shopInput` ever get incremented/decremented? If it never changes within the `while` loop, the output of `allShops[shopInput - 1].sellItem()` will never change, and you won't exit the while loop.

Comment: @StuartM it's taken as an input from the user, so it's never decremented. I can't give you the code here in the comments so I'll post a new question with a clearer inquiry and more code for you guys to see. I'll link you here.

Comment: @StuartM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308310/how-do-i-check-if-a-class-return-of-a-method-equals-null

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check for null.

```
if (allShops[shopInput - 1].sellItem() == null) {}
```

EDIT: removed unnecessary double negative